# flask TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response

Tags: python, flask

```py
    app = Flask(__name__,template_folder='templates')
    Bootstrap(app)
    @app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
    def index():
       return render_template("train.html")

    @app.route('/predict', methods=['GET','POST'])
    def predict():
    reviwequery = request.args.get('reviwequery')

    DataBase= pd.read_csv("data\\Fake_Review_Hotels2.csv")
    # Features and Labels
    DataBase_text = DataBase.text
    DataBase_label = DataBase.Label
    # Vectorization
 
    corpus = DataBase_text
    FE = TfidfVectorizer(lowercase = True, use_idf=True, smooth_idf=True, sublinear_tf=False)
    X_text = FE.fit_transform(corpus) 
    # Loading our ML Model    
    # Loading our ML Model
    RFC_model = open("models/RFCModel.pkl","rb")
    RandomFc = joblib.load(RFC_model)
    if request.method == 'POST':
       # reviwequery = request.form['reviwequery']
        data = [reviwequery]
        vect = FE.transform(data).toarray()
        my_prediction = RandomFc.predict(vect)

        print(my_prediction)
        if(my_prediction[0] == 1):
            output= "Fake"
        elif(my_prediction[0] == 0):
            output= "Real"
        else:
            output="Try Again!"
   
        return render_template("results.html",my_prediction='The Review is {}'.format(output))
```

I get this error

```
[2020-11-25 10:20:52,424] ERROR in app: Exception on /predict [GET]
"The view function did not return a valid response. The"
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
```

any idea please.

Answer (score 0):

Your `predict` function appears to accept GET requests but has no `return` statement if it receives one. You probably are accessing your `/predict` route via GET and Flask errors because it does not get a returned value from this function.